# How to serialize dynamic field names using JSON parser

Tags: json.net, json

I am using JSON.Net to serialize my objects. For eg, if this is my object

```
Class MainData
{
   [JsonProperty("keyValues")]
   string val;
}
```

the data for 'val' is a key value pair string like this key1:value1.
I have a scenario where I should not get the above 'keyValues' name in my final serialized string and instead get a serialized string which looks like this

```
{
    "key1":"value1"
}
```

Currently with my serializer I am getting this, which is not what I need

```
{
     "keyValues":"key:value1"
}
```

Can somebody guide me to any documentation/solution to dynamically assign the name of the field instead of using the default variable name/JSONProperty Name defined inside the object?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been struggling with this all day, what I've done is used a dictionary object and serialised this
however I had an error message that was "cannot serialise dictionary", should have read the whole message, "cannot serialise dictionary when the key is not a string or object"
this now works for me and gives me a key/value pair

i have the following objects

```
public class Meal {
public int mealId;
public int value;
public Meal(int MealId, int Value) {
mealId = MealId;
value = Value;
} }

public class Crew
{

public Meal[] AllocatedMeals {
get {
return new Meal[]{ 
new Meal(1085, 2),
new Meal(1086, 1) }; } }

public int AllocatedMealTotal {
get {
return this.AllocatedMeals.Sum(x => x.value); } }
}
```

then the following code

```
Dictionary<string,string> MealsAllocated = crew.AllocatedMeals.ToDictionary(x => x.mealId.ToString(), x => x.value.ToString());

return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
new {
Allocated = new {
Total = crew.AllocatedMealTotal,
Values = MealsAllocated } )
```

to get

```
"Allocated":{"Total":3,"Values":{"1085":"2","1086":"1"}}
```

Comment: that worked!!!, All I had to do was make ' string val ' to ' Dictionary<string, string> val '. It was so simple, thanks for your code, it helped me get the idea.